# Get 5V to USB Under Hood?

Tags: electrical

What's the easiest way to get 5V to a USB under the hood of a 2009 Civic (or preferrably, a general solution)? Basically, I want to put a custom theft-prevention device either underneath the dash or somewhere inside the engine bay, and I need a stable source of 5V (only when the car is running is fine) without messing with the wiring too much.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest picking up a feed from a wire which is live only when the ignition is on and hard wiring something like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Inverter-Regulator-Converter-Camcorder-HitCar-Dual-USB/dp/B071RKBH82) product into the loom.